# JavaScript animation using 'background-position-x' doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make an animation using `jquery-3.2.1` and the `css()` function. The animation works on all browsers except for IE, where it just jumps to the last frame on hover, instead of animating them

```js
$(".hi").hover(
  function() {
    $(".hi").animateSteps(-3429, -127, 37);
  },
  function() {
    $(".hi").animateSteps(0, 127, 37);
  }
);


$.fn.animateSteps = function(final, step, duration) {
  if (typeof t != "undefined") clearTimeout(t);
  var self = $(this);
  if (parseInt(self.css('background-position-x')) == final) return;
  self.css('background-position-x', '+=' + step + 'px');
  t = setTimeout(function() {
    self.animateSteps(final, step, duration);
  }, duration);
}
```

```css
.hi {
  width: 127px;
  height: 120px;
  background-image: url("https://image.ibb.co/c1L4LF/logo_sprites.png");
  background-position: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hi"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

[JS FIddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/gx9zrxq8/)

Update: There is no errors in console. It is IE11. It's just jumps on first/last position on hover/mouse out.

Comment: Can you elaborate what "not working" means?

Comment: Also, what version(s) of IE?

Comment: It's just show first and last step of animation on hover/mouse out. IE11

Comment: What error is thrown in dev tools console. Would be a big clue!

Comment: There is no errors in console. It's just wokrs not like in other browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have good news and bad news. Bad news, is I really don't know what the issue is. Good new is I found a fix. [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gx9zrxq8/15/)

Replacing `background-position-x` with `backgroundPosition` seems to do the trick. Some debugging was showing that IE kept showing a null value for `background-position-x` but would show a `backgroundPosition` value in the DOM explorer.

Why? I have no idea, everything I've read says that IE should support `background-position-x`, yet I couldn't get it to. If anyone knows or has a guess as to why this is, please feel free to chime in, as I'm interested in knowing!

```js
$(".hi").hover(
  function() {
    $(".hi").animateSteps(-3429, -127, 37);
  },
  function() {
    $(".hi").animateSteps(0, 127, 37);
  }
);


$.fn.animateSteps = function(final, step, duration) {
  if (typeof t != "undefined") clearTimeout(t);
  var self = $(this);
  if (parseInt(self.css('backgroundPosition')) == final) return;
  // console.log(self.css('background-position-x'));
  console.log(self)
  self.css('backgroundPosition', '+=' + step + 'px');
  t = setTimeout(function() {
    self.animateSteps(final, step, duration);
  }, duration);
}
```

```css
.hi {
  width: 127px;
  height: 120px;
  background-image: url("https://image.ibb.co/c1L4LF/logo_sprites.png");
  background-position: 0px;
  background-position-x: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hi"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I would never get it by myself.

Comment: @Oleksii sure thing :). If it fixed your problem, please mark the answer as the solution so others with the same problem can find it